# How to create predicate that is true if gets different values

Tags: prolog

I would like to ask how to create predicate that returns true if gets different values.

I have this database:

```
fruit(apple).
fruit(peach).
fruit(banana).
fruit(orange).
fruit(mandarine).
fruit(plum).
```

I need predicate `threeFruits/3` that takes three fruits and says if they are different i.e.

```
threeFruits(apple,peach,banana). -> true
threeFruits(apple,apple,banana).  -> false   .. etc.
```

The code I have so far is not correct:

```
threeFruits(X,Y,Z):- fruit(X),fruit(Y),fruit(Z).
```

I tried also unification, but it can tell me only if they are same, but not working for different.

```
threeFruits(fruit(X),fruit(X),fruit(X)).
```

Thank you in advance for any hint.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `X`, `Y`, `Z` are really atoms for which `fruit/1` is valid, you can test whether they pairwise "do not unify" by using the negation of [`=/2`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(%3D)/2) (i.e. the negation of unification)

```
threeFruits(X,Y,Z) :-
   assertion(fruit(X)),
   assertion(fruit(Y)),
   assertion(fruit(Z)),
   X\=Y,Y\=Z,X\=Z.
```

Alternatively, you can use the negation of [`==/2`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(%3D%3D)/2) to check whether they pairwise "are not the same":

```
threeFruits(X,Y,Z) :-
   assertion(fruit(X)),
   assertion(fruit(Y)),
   assertion(fruit(Z)),
   X\==Y,Y\==Z,X\==Z.
```

Comment: What's `assertion/1`? That is not a standard (official or de facto) predicate and this is a **generic** Prolog question. If your proposed solution only works on a specific Prolog system, be sure to identify it.

Comment: @PauloMoura True, but the original poster can just leave it out after all: It's an assertion (I sure hope op does know about assertions; should be the first thing taught after the NOP instruction.) Not standard, sure, but it should be. No assertions, no dice. Historical note: "assertions" appear in 1949 in Alan Turing's [Checking a Large Routine](http://www.turingarchive.org/browse.php/B/8) and 1963 in Goldstine/von Neumann "Planning and Coding Problems for an Electronic Computing Instrument", p.12 ([PDF](https://www.ias.edu/sites/default/files/library/pdfs/ecp/planningcodingof0103inst.pdf)).

Comment: Do you think if we ONLY use X\=Y,Y\=Z,X\=Z that would be enough?

Comment: @ReemaQKhan It depends.